# Relation between probability and expected value

Tags: probability, expectation

I came across the following notation:

$$
Err = P\{a < \theta\} \\
Err = E[1_{[a< \theta ]}]
$$

where $1_{[\pi ]}$ is the indicator, and is equal to 1 if $\pi$ is true and 0 otherwise.

I don't understand why the probability of an event is equal to the expected value of the number of times the event happens.

Comment: There is no concept of an event happening some "number of times." Either an event occurs or it does not. So while it's true that $1_{A}$ is in a certain sense "the number of times the event occurs" (where it is understood that the only options are zero or one times), another phrase like "whether the event occurs or not" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an event. $E[1_{[A]}]=0 \cdot P(A^c) + 1 \cdot P(A) = P(A)$. This occurs because when $A^c$ occurs, the value of $1_{[A]}$ is $0$ and when $A$ occurs, the value of $1_{[A]}$ is 1.